# Angular $scope not updating in Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a ng-repeat list, that has a button that changes the state of the item, when I click the button I run the following:

```
$scope.fav = function(item) {
  var i = $scope.news.indexOf(item);
  console.log('index', i);
  console.log('$scope.news[i].fav', $scope.news[i].fav);
  console.log('$scope.news[i]', $scope.news[i]);
  if ($scope.news[i].fav === 0) {
    console.log('is 0');
    $scope.news[i].fav = 1;
  } else {
    console.log('its not 0');
    $scope.news[i].fav = 0;
  }
};
```

It finds the object without a problem, but

```
$scope.news[i].fav = 1;
```

or

```
$scope.news[i].fav = 0;
```

Never changes the final value. (Keeps returning 0)

Already tried adding $scope.$apply(); with no avail..

**MARKUP:**

```
<ion-list class="list item-text-wrap" can-swipe="true">
  <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left animated fadeIn" ng-repeat="item in news | filter: {title: sinTildes} | orderBy: '-pubDate'" href="#/feed/{{item.source}}/{{item.link}}/{{item.title}}" ng-click="openNews(item)">
    <img class="gm-thumbnail" src="{{item.image}}">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <div class="gm-bottom-left">
      <h4 class="dark">{{item.source}} -
        <span am-time-ago="item.pubDate"> </span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="gm-bottom-right">
      <span class="icon ion-ios-eye ng-hide font-medium assertive" ng-show="item.rss"></span>
    </div>
    <ion-option-button class="button-stable" ng-click="fav(item)">
      <span ng-show="item.fav">&nbsp;<i class="icon ion-ios-star energized animated fadeIn"></i></span>
      <span ng-show="!item.fav">&nbsp;<i class="icon ion-ios-star-outline dark animated fadeIn"></i></span>
    </ion-option-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Show your markup code as well.

Comment: Could you get a copy of your js/code/markup into a jsfiddle? Easier to make changes there to verify everything is working.

Comment: Hard to say without a plunkr or similar. But why don't you 1. use a boolean rather than 0/1? 2. directly modify the item passed as argument rather than finding its index in $scope.news and use $scope.new[i] to refer to the item passed as argument?

Comment: @JBNizet because SQLite tends to convert it to string, thus making it harder to rely on words (and in bigger amounts of data it consumes space). Regarding the $scope.new[i] didn't work either....after all the attempts before posting this question that was what got "closer"

Comment: Thaanks for your comments, I will try to set up a plunker/JSfiddle when I can, but I forgot to mention its on Ionic, i think its very likely that there's a angular.copy needed somewhere (had that issue in prior apps)

Comment: @Wigiri why do u need to have 2 span with ng-show?. You can use only one span and change the class using ng-show depending on the value of item.fav

Comment: @SwapnilShende, Thanks for your suggestion! I was testing the code and to avoid any other issues I made the code easier to debug (In the controller I also have an if...else that I already merged into one statement.)

Answer (score 0):

It is an Ionic issue.

I fixed it using **angular.copy** like this:

```
$scope.fav = function(item) {
  var i = $scope.news.indexOf(item);
  var news = angular.copy($scope.news);
  console.log('index', i);
  console.log('news[i].fav', news[i].fav);
  console.log('news[i]', news[i]);
  if (news[i].fav === 0) {
    console.log('is 0');
    DBnews.fav(news[i].link, 1).then(function() {
      news[i].fav = 1;
      $scope.news[i] = {};
      $scope.news[i] = angular.copy(news[i]);
    })
  } else {
    console.log('its not 0');
    DBnews.fav(news[i].link, 0).then(function() {
      news[i].fav = 0;
      $scope.news[i] = {};
      $scope.news[i] = angular.copy(news[i]);
    });
  }
};
```